# What is "capult"?

Tags: meaning

There is a Tertullian quote in one of the editions of Gibbon (see [the asterisked note here for the original](https://archive.org/details/historyofdecline55gibb/page/613/mode/1up)).

> Nam proximè ad lenonem damnando Christianam, potius quam ad leonem,
> confessi estis labem pudicitiae apud nos atrociorem omni poenâ et omni
> morte reputari, Apol. capult.

I searched and found the Tertullian quote, thus discovering that the "Apol. capult." isn't part of the quote. The "Apol." is for *Apologeticus*, the source of the quote.

What I can't find is the "capult." I've done quite a bit of searching, and I can't find that word in any Latin dictionary, nor can I find it as an abbreviation (in case that period is doing double-duty).

Is "capult" a word or an abbreviation, if the latter what is it an abbreviation for, and what does it mean in this context?

Comment: Could it perhaps be a typesetting error for "caput 1", that is, chapter 1 of the _Apologeticus_?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing it's probably a typographical error. The actual passage comes from [chapter 50](http://www.tertullian.org/latin/apologeticus.htm) (caput L). Originally it might have been spelled "caput l" and somewhere along the way it might have been transposed into "capult."

There is no Latin word *capult* nor is there any abbreviation for it that I can find.

Comment: Good grief. The site I found the quote on only showed a small section of the text at a time, and it was the 10/11/12/13 smaller numbers. I didn't see the chapter#, or I might have (more likely my wife, who has some Latin) been able to put that together. Thanks very much!